# Why is a simple loop optimized when the limit is 959 but not 960?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, clang

Consider this simple loop:

```
float f(float x[]) {
  float p = 1.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 959; i++)
    p += 1;
  return p;
}
```

If you compile with gcc 7 (snapshot) or clang (trunk) with `-march=core-avx2  -Ofast` you get something very similar to.

```
.LCPI0_0:
        .long   1148190720              # float 960
f:                                      # @f
        vmovss  xmm0, dword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_0] # xmm0 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
        ret
```

In other words it just sets the answer to 960 without looping.

However if you change the code to:

```
float f(float x[]) {
  float p = 1.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 960; i++)
    p += 1;
  return p;
}
```

The produced assembly actually performs the loop sum? For example clang gives:

```
.LCPI0_0:
        .long   1065353216              # float 1
.LCPI0_1:
        .long   1086324736              # float 6
f:                                      # @f
        vmovss  xmm0, dword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_0] # xmm0 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
        vxorps  ymm1, ymm1, ymm1
        mov     eax, 960
        vbroadcastss    ymm2, dword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_1]
        vxorps  ymm3, ymm3, ymm3
        vxorps  ymm4, ymm4, ymm4
.LBB0_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        vaddps  ymm0, ymm0, ymm2
        vaddps  ymm1, ymm1, ymm2
        vaddps  ymm3, ymm3, ymm2
        vaddps  ymm4, ymm4, ymm2
        add     eax, -192
        jne     .LBB0_1
        vaddps  ymm0, ymm1, ymm0
        vaddps  ymm0, ymm3, ymm0
        vaddps  ymm0, ymm4, ymm0
        vextractf128    xmm1, ymm0, 1
        vaddps  ymm0, ymm0, ymm1
        vpermilpd       xmm1, xmm0, 1   # xmm1 = xmm0[1,0]
        vaddps  ymm0, ymm0, ymm1
        vhaddps ymm0, ymm0, ymm0
        vzeroupper
        ret
```

Why is this and why is it exactly the same for clang and gcc?

---

The limit for the same loop if you replace `float` with `double` is 479. This is the same for gcc and clang again.

**Update 1**

It turns out that gcc 7 (snapshot) and clang (trunk) behave very differently. clang optimizes out the loops for all limits less than 960 as far as I can tell.  gcc on the other hand is sensitive to the exact value and doesn't have an upper limit . For example it **does not** optimize out the loop when the limit is 200 (as well as many other values) but it **does** when the limit is 202 and 20002 (as well as many other values).

Comment: `max-unroll-times` and other unrolling options https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.4/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Comment: What Sulthan probably means is that 1) compiler unrolls the loop and 2) once it's unrolled sees that the sum operations can be grouped into one. If the loop isn't unrolled, the operations cannot be grouped.

Comment: @coderredoc It makes no difference.

Comment: Ah I was simply thinking if the compiler just unrolls the instruction for less looping kind of being safe that it won't overflow or sth...But I am not sure if it is the reason...for 1000 it simply does all the addition. to avoid that.

Comment: Having an odd number of loops makes unrolling more complicated, the last few iterations have to be done specially.  That might well be enough to bump the optimizer into a mode where it no longer can recognize the shortcut.  It is pretty likely, it first has to add the code for the special case and would then have to remove it again.  Using the optimizer between the ears is always best :)

Comment: @HansPassant It is also optimized for any number smaller than 959.

Comment: Wouldn't this usually be done with induction variable elimination, instead of unrolling an insane amount? Unrolling by a factor of 959 is crazy.

Comment: @harold Right! That's exactly my thinking.

Comment: The value reduced when you used double. My reason kind of goes with that.

Comment: Does it differ if you adjust the floating point flags like `-ffast-math` and `-fexcess-precision`?  Even though 1, 960, and 961 can all be represented exactly in IEEE floating point, I'm wondering if the optimizer couldn't prove that past some point.  I'm also curious if the unused `x` parameter affects the results.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy There is no such flag afaict. You can play with it here though. https://godbolt.org/g/qvxqRo

Comment: @eleanora: The question is tagged with gcc, and the gcc options list several options that affect the strictness of floating point operations:  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Comment: Note that the decision to unroll or not changes depending not on how big the number gets, but rather its particular value - for example try it with 951 and 953 and you'll see a constant, but with 952 the loop is retained. Maybe it is something with floating-point precision!

Comment: @SlimsGhost That does show a difference between gcc and clang. For 952 clang optimizes out the loop but gcc doesn't. See https://godbolt.org/g/oiMUZS

Comment: @SlimsGhost: Check Hans Passant comment: "Having an odd number of loops makes unrolling more complicated". Looks like what you said (only the opposite, but you may be on to something). Anyway I love the "use the optimizer between your ears": so true.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre 952 is an even number :)

Comment: mmmmh let me check, yes, you're right :) I was saying it's the opposite to Hans remark. But it seems related at least. And let's not forget that this is an academic case. Noone does that purposedly in a real program. I used to think that the better the optimizer works the worse is the original code. Someone told me he gained a x10 factor with some compiler, but that was because his code was written by a bunch of bozos. I tried on my code and gained almost nothing.

Comment: 960 has a whole bunch of factors (28 of them).  Not sure if this has any impact on making it the cutoff point.

Comment: The "optimized" vector loop does the addition 192 elements at a time, and 960 = 5*192. Have you tried 961 ? Is this linked to loop vectorization ?

Comment: For 961 you get https://godbolt.org/g/1bX3KR .  gcc and clang are clearly doing something very different.

Comment: @eleanora I played with that compilre explorer and the following seems to hold (talking about the gcc snapshot only): If the loop count is a multiple of 4 and at least 72, then the loop is *not* unrolled (or rather, unrolled by a factor of 4); otherwise, the whole loop is replaced by a constant - even if the loop count is 2000000001. My suspicion: **premature optimization** (as in, a premature "hey, a multiple of 4, that's good for unrolling" that block further optimization vs. a more thorough "What's the deal with this loop anyway?")

Answer (score 92, accepted):

#### TL;DR

By default, the current snapshot GCC 7 behaves inconsistently, while previous versions have default limit due to [`PARAM_MAX_COMPLETELY_PEEL_TIMES`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/params.def#L321), which is 16. It can be overridden from command-line.

The rationale of the limit is to prevent too aggressive loop unrolling, that can be a [double-edged sword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159460/why-is-a-simple-loop-optimized-when-the-limit-is-959-but-not-960/42162726?noredirect=1#comment71509899_42162726).

### GCC version <= 6.3.0

The relevant optimization option for GCC is [`-fpeel-loops`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-fpeel-loops-984), which is enabled indirectly along with flag `-Ofast` (emphasis is mine):

> Peels loops for which there is enough information that they do not
>   roll much (from profile feedback or **static analysis**). It also turns on
>   complete loop peeling (i.e. **complete removal of loops with small
>   constant number of iterations**).
>
> Enabled with `-O3` and/or `-fprofile-use`.

More details can be obtained by adding `-fdump-tree-cunroll`:

```
$ head test.c.151t.cunroll 

;; Function f (f, funcdef_no=0, decl_uid=1919, cgraph_uid=0, symbol_order=0)

Not peeling: upper bound is known so can unroll completely
```

The message is from [`/gcc/tree-ssa-loop-ivcanon.c`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/tree-ssa-loop-ivcanon.c#L1010):

```
if (maxiter >= 0 && maxiter <= npeel)
    {
      if (dump_file)
        fprintf (dump_file, "Not peeling: upper bound is known so can "
         "unroll completely\n");
      return false;
    }
```

hence [`try_peel_loop`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/tree-ssa-loop-ivcanon.c#L960) function returns `false`.

More verbose output can be reached with `-fdump-tree-cunroll-details`:

```
Loop 1 iterates 959 times.
Loop 1 iterates at most 959 times.
Not unrolling loop 1 (--param max-completely-peeled-times limit reached).
Not peeling: upper bound is known so can unroll completely
```

It is possible to tweak the limits by plaing with `max-completely-peeled-insns=n` and `max-completely-peel-times=n` params:

> ```
> max-completely-peeled-insns
> ```
>
> The maximum number of insns of a completely peeled loop.
>
> ```
> max-completely-peel-times
> ```
>
> The maximum number of iterations of a loop to be suitable for complete
>   peeling.

To learn more about insns, you can refer to [GCC Internals Manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Insns.html).

For instance, if you compile with following options:

```
-march=core-avx2 -Ofast --param max-completely-peeled-insns=1000 --param max-completely-peel-times=1000
```

then code turns into:

```
f:
        vmovss  xmm0, DWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        ret
.LC0:
        .long   1148207104
```

### Clang

I am not sure what Clang actually does and how to tweak its limits, but as I observed, you could force it to evaluate the final value by marking the loop with [unroll pragma](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#pragma-unroll-pragma-nounroll), and it will remove it completely:

```
#pragma unroll
for (int i = 0; i < 960; i++)
    p++;
```

results into:

```
.LCPI0_0:
        .long   1148207104              # float 961
f:                                      # @f
        vmovss  xmm0, dword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_0] # xmm0 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
        ret
```

Comment: Thank you for this very nice answer. As others have pointed out, gcc seems to be sensitive to the exact limit size. For example it fails to eliminate the loop for 912 https://godbolt.org/g/EQJHvT .  What does fdump-tree-cunroll-details say in that case?

Comment: In fact even 200 has this problem. This is all in a snapshot of gcc 7 that godbolt provides. https://godbolt.org/g/Vg3SVs  This doesn't apply to clang at all.

Comment: The oddity is that it works for 202.  There are plenty of pairs of values like this less than 960 where it works for one but not the other.

Comment: @elenora: The latest snaphot behaves inconsistently, but I am not sure what is the root cause. OTOH, the 6.3.0 does not have such oddity.

Comment: Gcc 6.3 on godbolt doesn't do the loop elimination at all as far as I can see.

Comment: @eleanora: It does when count is less than 18. Nevethless, I wouldn't count on default limit size, as it may be changed without any notice.

Comment: You explain the mechanics of the peeling, but not what the relevance of 960 is or why there is even a limit at all

Comment: @M.M: The peeling behavior is completely different between GCC 6.3.0 and latest snaphost. In case of the former, I strongly suspect, that the hard-coded limit is enforced by `PARAM_MAX_COMPLETELY_PEEL_TIMES` param, that is defined in `/gcc/params.def:321` with the value 16.

Comment: You might want to mention *why* GCC deliberately limits itself in this way.  Specifically, if you unroll your loops too aggressively, the binary gets bigger and you're less likely to fit into L1 cache.  Cache misses are potentially [quite expensive](https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832) relative to saving a few conditional jumps, assuming good branch prediction (which you will have, for a typical loop).

Answer (score 20):

After reading Sulthan's comment, I guess that:

1. The compiler fully unrolls the loop if the loop counter is constant (and not too high)
2. Once it's unrolled, the compiler sees that the sum operations can be grouped into one.

If the loop isn't unrolled for some reason (here: it would generate too many statements with `1000`), the operations cannot be grouped.

The compiler *could* see that the unroll of 1000 statements amounts to a single addition, but step 1 & 2 described above are two separate optimizations, so it cannot take the "risk" of unrolling, not knowing if the operations can be grouped (example: a function call cannot be grouped).

Note: This is a corner case: Who uses a loop to add the same thing over again? In that case, don't rely on the compiler possible unroll/optimise; directly write the proper operation in one instruction.

Comment: then can you focus on that `not too high` part? I mean why the risk is not there in case of `100` ? I have guessed something ...in my comment above..it can be the reason for that?

Comment: I think that the compiler isn't aware of the floating point inaccuracy that it could trigger. I guess it's just an instruction size limit. You have `max-unrolled-insns` alongside `max-unrolled-times`

Comment: Ah it was kind of my thought or guess...wish to get a more clear reasoning.

Comment: your question is very good: 10 upvotes is rare. you'll be on the higest voted tonight (means: more upvotes :))

Comment: Interestingly if you change the `float` to an `int`, gcc compiler is able to strength-reduce the loop regardless of the iteration count, due to its induction variable optimizations (`-fivopts`).  But those don't seem to work for `float`s.

Comment: Note that the decision to unroll or not changes depending not on how big the number gets, but rather its particular value - for example try it with 951 and 953 and you'll see a constant, but with 952 the loop is retained. Maybe it *is* something with floating-point precision!

Comment: Maybe so, but I doubt that the compiler is able to predict floating point precision errors. You are in charge of making sure you get the best precision. I remember changing optimization options and getting different floating point results in some signal processing stuff I was reworking.

Comment: I can't speak to gcc's optimizations, but the C++ language permit floating point results to be any value within the error bound on the operation (typically 0.5, 1 or 2 times the lowest bit).  Given that, a compiler is within its right to pick which of those values actually occurs, so it could choose the most convenient floating point inaccuracies possible for maximum optimization.

Comment: @CortAmmon Right, and I recall reading some people who were surprised and upset that GCC uses MPFR to precisely calculate very large numbers, giving rather different results than the equivalent floating point operations which would have accumulated error and precision loss. Goes to show that many people compute floating point the wrong way.

Answer (score 13):

Very good question!

You seem to have hit a limit on the number of iterations or operations the compiler tries to inline when simplifying the code.  As documented by Grzegorz Szpetkowski, there are compiler specific ways to tweak these limits with pragmas or command line options.

You can also play with [Godbolt's Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/fe7sSL) to compare how different compilers and options impact the code generated: `gcc 6.2` and `icc 17` still inline the code for 960, whereas `clang 3.9` does not (with the default Godbolt configuration, it actually stops inlining at 73).

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clear the versions of gcc and clang I was using. See https://godbolt.org/g/FfwWjL .  I am using -Ofast for example.